# Unknown html tag warning of Bootstrap-Vue.js support in WebStorm

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, webstorm, bootstrap-4

I'm using WebStorm 2017.2.4 and webpack Vue.js project. I have added [bootstrap-vue.js](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org) to my project and would like to see hints for it and components support.

But instead of that I have got "Unknown html tag" warning.

[image: screen]

BTW: bootstrap-vue works as expected when running project.

Do you have any suggestions how to make it work?

Comment: I’m having this exact problem with WebStorm 2017.3.3

Comment: Me too. Can you set a bounty for this question?

Comment: @JanTajovsky what do you mean?

Comment: @Bullet-tooth https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty

Comment: What happens, when you click on "more" ?

In phpStorm it is possible to add custom tags and attributes as valid.

Comment: JetBrains Support contacted.
It's a problem with dynamic binding of mixins, directives etc of VueJS.
They are working on it.

Comment: @Snsxn could you provide the link to reported issue? I don't want to create duplicate. Thx

Comment: @PrzemekNowak issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-31682. related to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-30742

Answer (score 14):

### UPDATED on 2019/07/30

PHPShtorm(WebStorm) was updated to 2019.2 and now they added better support for vuejs libraries:
https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2019/07/webstorm-2019-2/#development_with_vue
I've just tested and it works.
[image]

### OLD answer

I solved this issue by adding components manually.
According to: https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/#individual-components-and-directives 
I created new file, e.g. bootstrap.js then register globally components which required

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css';
import Vue from 'vue';
import navbar from 'bootstrap-vue/es/components/navbar/navbar';
import container from 'bootstrap-vue/es/components/layout/container';
// ...

Vue.component('b-navbar', navbar);
Vue.component('b-container', container);
// ...
```

It work for me in phpstorm 2018.1

Comment: I created all aliases. Just create custom file e.g. `vue-boostrap.js` paste this: pastebin.com/Z3cBgPyp
 and import this file in `main.js`

Comment: Even after register a component, this is still no content assistant for tag properties, in `WebStorm 2019.1.3`.

Comment: I would not say register component one by one manually is best approach

Answer (score 5):

#Updated: There're two ways to fix "Unknown html tag" warning: (Global and Local Registration)

1. **Global Registration :**

   You should have to register your component globally `Vue.component(tagName, options)` before creating the new Vue instance. For example:

   ```
    Vue.component('my-component', {
      // options
    })
   ```

   Once registered, a component can be used in an instance’s template as a custom element, `<my-component></my-component>`. Make sure the component is registered before you instantiate the root Vue instance. Here’s the full example:

   **<sub>HTML:</sub>**

   ```
    <div id="example">
      <my-component></my-component>
    </div>
   ```

   **<sub>JS:</sub>**

   ```
    // global register
    Vue.component('my-component', {
      template: '<div>A custom component!</div>'
    })

    // create a root instance
    new Vue({
      el: '#example'
    })
   ```

   <sub>**Which will render HTML:**</sub>:

   ```
    <div id="example">
      <div>A custom component!</div>
    </div>
   ```
2. **Local Registration :**

   You don’t have to register every component globally. You can make a component available only in the scope of another instance/component by registering it with the `components` instance option:

   ```
    var Child = {
      template: '<div>A custom component!</div>'
    }

    new Vue({
      // ...
      components: {
        // <my-component> will only be available in parent's template
        'my-component': Child
      }
    })
   ```

   > The same encapsulation applies for other registerable Vue features, such as directives.

Read more at https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-Components

---

#Before Updated:

> In WebStorm, a **library** is a file or a set of files whose functions and methods are added to WebStorm's internal knowledge in addition to the functions and methods that WebStorm retrieves from the project code that you edit. In the scope of a project, its libraries by default are **write-protected**.

> WebStorm uses libraries only to enhance coding assistance (that is, code completion, syntax highlighting, navigation, and documentation lookup). *Please* note that a library is not a way to manage your project dependencies.

Source: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/configuring-javascript-libraries.html

Simply, upgrade WebStorm from version 2017.2.4 to [2017.3](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/whatsnew/) which fixed this issue. It is tested.

Comment: @Snsxn what's about 2017.3

Comment: @AsifAli72090 It is not working in 2017.3 The IDE does not recognize <b-* tags.

I think it might be connected to the way how bootstrap register its components.

When I register the component using Vue.use() IDE can pick it up.

Answer (score 4):

Bootstrap vue uses very dynamic way of defining components. I am using PyCharm with vuejs extension which is unable to resolve the components when registered using

```
import { Layout } from 'bootstrap-vue/es/components'

Vue.use(Layout)
```

What I use to do is make a new file `bootstrap.js` in `components` directory, and register all bootstrap components I would use like

```
import Vue from 'vue'

import bContainer from 'bootstrap-vue/es/components/layout/container'
import bRow from 'bootstrap-vue/es/components/layout/row'
import bCol from 'bootstrap-vue/es/components/layout/col'

Vue.component('b-container', bContainer);
Vue.component('b-col', bCol);
Vue.component('b-row', bRow);
```

and then import this file in `main.js`

```
import './components/bootstrap'
```

Just a little cleaner solution.

Comment: I created all aliases. Just create custom file e.g. `vue-boostrap.js` paste this:
https://pastebin.com/Z3cBgPyp
and import this file in `main.js`

Comment: Using phpStorm 2019.2 isn't necessary to import the `vue-bootstrap.js`. PhpStorm read the file from project and Vue is not affected.